# Programatically changing an Azure password with Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I currently have some Azure AD accounts created that are used with RBAC within things like automation.

Currently changing passwords for these accounts is a slightly labour intensive process. With a number of moving parts needing to be updated at once. As well as a manual step to change the password in the first place.

Is it possible to change an Azure AD password via Powershell. (Ideally only using Azure Cmdlets) thus allowing me to automate the entire process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you install the [Azure AD PowerShell module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx) you can run this:

```
$msolcred = get-credential
connect-msolservice -credential $msolcred

$user = "usertochange@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com";

#optionally set password not to expire
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user -PasswordNeverExpires $true

$pwd = read-host "Please enter the new AAD user's password:"

MSOnlineExtended\Set-MsolUserPassword -UserPrincipalName $user -NewPassword $pwd -ForceChangePassword $false
```